# Using libCurl to POST adds unknown header and footer

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I'm using libCurl in c++ to make a POST request of an xml file to my server. The post works, I receive the xml on my server. However the xml also has a strange header & footer around the xml:

```
------------------------------b6966127f870Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myName"; filename="myFile.xml"Content-Type: application/xml<CORRECT XML FILE HERE>------------------------------b6966127f870--
```

What is this header/footer?

Can I get rid of it? Or should I just parse around it?

Is curl adding these?

Here are the relevant curl calls I make to post the xml file.

```
void CurlUtils::postFileToURL(const char* const inFile,
                              const char* const urlString)
{
  // Setup
  CURL* const curl = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

  // Post
  struct curl_httppost* post = NULL;
  struct curl_httppost* last = NULL;
  curl_formadd(&post, &last,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "myName",
               CURLFORM_FILE, inFile,
               CURLFORM_END);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, urlString);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, post);
  curl_easy_perform(curl);

  // Cleanup ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `CURLOPT_HTTPPOST` which makes a multipart formpost to the server. A multipart formpost is a series of parts with MIME style separators and a set of headers for each part, exactly what you see there.

If you want a plain POST without the multipart stuff, use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` or set a read callback and use `CURLOPT_POST`.